# Xcode 12 SwiftUI app rejected for UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities plist key

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, appstore-approval

I've just created a new iOS app and submitted it to Apple review.
They've rejected it because of the following:

> Guideline 2.3 - Performance - Accurate Metadata
>
> We were unable to install the app on iPhone. The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a way that the app will not install on iPhone .
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please check the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key to verify that it contains only the attributes required for your app features or the attributes that must not be present on the device. Attributes specified by a dictionary should be set to true if they are required and false if they must not be present on the device.
>
> Resources
>
> Please review the Technical Q&A 1397: Understanding the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key for information on the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key.
>
> You may also wish to review the dictionary keys table in the "Declaring the Required Device Capabilities" section of the App Programming Guide for iOS.

I've not changed the value of `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` so I'm confused about what could be wrong with it. Here are the steps I took:

- I created the app using Xcode 12.0
- I used the SwiftUI template
- I'm supporting iOS 14 only
- My app doesn't need any particular device
  requirements (for example GPS)

The plist key that this template generates is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchScreen</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Should I just remove this key entirely? Is it a bug that Xcode creates an app with this key?

Comment: You may need to talk to the review team.  I've seen discussions of that rejection reason that suggest it has been used for various unrelated metadata problems, including bad characters in an app name.

Comment: could you include the app name to remove this ambiguity?

Comment: armv7 is supported by default across all the latest iOS devices and is the default value in Xcode 12, so it's not wrong.

Comment: this question should be re-opened IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it was just Apple Review forgetting how to install apps on their devices. Messaging them and asking them to try again solve it.